# Date to timestamp

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to convert this date string 2014-07-17T22:41:17+0000 to a timestmap, similar to this: 1405645259000.

I've tried something similar to this:

```
String string = "January 2, 2010";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM d, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```

How do I convert this (2014-07-17T22:41:17+000) to a Date? What is the correct format? I'm at a loss.

Comment: Please read this post. Hope this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24726584/how-to-compare-two-times-in-java/24726693#24726693

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Your date string has the same format as

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ  //Eg: 2001-07-04T12:08:56-0700
```

So, your code should be:

```
String string = "2014-07-17T22:41:17+0000";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
System.out.println(date);
```

Answer (score 3):

use this pattern:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(string);
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2014-07-17T22:41:17+0000" )
              .toInstant()
              .toEpochMilli()
```

## Avoid `java.util.Date`

Your question is easy in Joda-Time or the new java.time package in Java 8. Avoid java.util.Date and .Calendar as they are notoriously troublesome.

## ISO 8601

Your String is in standard format, complying with ISO 8601. Both libraries mentioned above use ISO 8601 as their defaults for parsing and generating strings.

## java.time

The `OffsetDateTime` class represents a moment on the timeline with an offset-from-UTC and with a resolution in nanoseconds.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( "2014-07-17T22:41:17+0000" );
```

From there you can ask for the count-of-milliseconds-since-epoch via the `Instant` class. The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli();
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

---

## Joda-Time

Example code on Joda-Time 2.3.

```
long millisSinceEpoch = new DateTime( "2014-07-17T22:41:17+0000" ).getMillis();
```